# How to show lookup like data in Kendo UI grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a data

```
var obj= [
    {a:"a1",b:"8/11/2013", c:10},
    {a:"a1",b:"9/11/2013", c:15},
    {a:"b1",b:"8/11/2013", c:16}
];

name  August  September
a1       10        15
b1       16
```

In kendo ui grid?. I know It can be possible in kendo pivot table but I want to do it in kendo grid so that I can edit and pass the data to controller.

Note: I'm using Kendo js files for grid

Comment: Man, please edit your question and explain yourself better. Your post is a mess

Comment: Please show us what you have done, so that we know exactly where you get stuck.